Access OCI Object Storage with GlassFish 7.9
I am doing an application using GlassFish 7.9, and Jakarta EE 10, to upload some images to an OCI bucket, but it is not working because of a certification error.
jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (outbound opc-request-id: CAA00349C4E04214A8FE4TLAS232E1BB)
com.oracle.bmc.model.BmcException: (-1, null, true) jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (outbound opc-request-id: CAA00349C4E04214A8FE4TLAS232E1BB)

I've already tried a few things, like adding the OCI certificate into the GlassFish keystore.jks, and also into cacerts.jks, but it still didn't work.
I've tried this behavior with a SpringBoot application, and it works well. What do I need to do to work with this in a Jakarta EE 10 application with GlassFish?
Thanks

You need to add the certificate to the cacerts.jks trust store in GlassFish. You wrote that you did it but maybe you made some mistake. GlassFish doesn't trust any remote certificates, not even those trusted by the JVM. All trusted certificates or certificates of their authorities need to be in the cacerts.jks truststore.

If you need more help, raise an issue in the GlassFish issue tracker or contact me or my colleagues at https://omnifish.ee/contact-us/
